# Xcode, can't remove "Launch image" from project

Tags: xcode, image, launch

I am playing with my Xcode, following tutorial, learning this stuff. I added an image to "Launch Images", rebuilt my project, it showed up.

- I removed the image, rebuilt my project .... image still flashed before app started
- I deleted my project, redid my project, this time with no image, launched the app and voila ... image is still there?
- I reset simulator counters and settings ... same issue

Is there a permanent location where this file can be removed from? Is there a cache that needs to be reset etc?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

iPhone Simulator caches stuff. Try a clean build, or actually deleting the app from the simulator (by holding down on a home screen icon until it wiggles, then X-ing it).

Comment: The same goes for the device - if you don't delete the app from the device before deploying a developer build onto it, the old files remain in place.

Comment: Indeed this was the issue. Thank you

Comment: Was beating the wall with my head on this one.  Delete the app from the device, Product > Clean got it for me.  Thanks Inspire48 & Jim!

Comment: in xcode 7.3 i also had to reboot my device. any uiimage i change in the launch screen storyboard wouldn't update from the old one to the new one.

Answer (score 3):

With the project open `Goto xcode > Product > Clean`

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the project folder, go to Resources folder and **delete the folders called splash and icon** (do this from **both from Xcode and Finder**). Also delete the app from either the device or the simulator by pressing on it and x-ing it out then go to **Product->Clean**.

I know this was very painful, but now you can set the new icons and launch images from Xcode.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the image is not in the project folder anywhere, also ensure that in the info.plist there is no value relating to launch image.

Comment: The only image in place is the icon image and it's different one from the one flashing. Checked directory structure as well - no image in question

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an image named "Default.png" (or whatever suffix)?  When assigning an image to the default launch, Xcode makes a copy and renames it "Default".